# Cannot get the downloading file name from Android download manager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using Android download manager for my application and it works perfectly. But I need to get downloading file name when it's stored. I didn't get the file name and it get's an error. I have tried all previous solutions as well. Please help me to fix this.

```
        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                boolean isDownloading = false;
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterByStatus(
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|
                                DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|
                                DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|
                                DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
                );
                Cursor cur = mgr.query(query);
    String filename="";

                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
String filePath = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
        filename = filePath.substring( filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filePath.length() );
                }



                    Uri source = Uri.parse(myWebsites[j]);


                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);

                    request.setNotificationVisibility(
                            DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED
                    );


                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyDownloadManager/"+folderName,                    filename );

                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();


                    long id = mgr.enqueue(request);

                cur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work fine if you set filter by downloadId

```
query.setFilterById(id);
```